# 'TRY - CATCH' statements not working as expected inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, try-catch

This code is working without any error. But I wanted to see the output of a try-catch statement and wrapped the body of the procedure with a try-catch statement and did a mistake purposely. However, the error doesn't display as an output in the grid result set. Still, it comes out in the default way. I need to know whether my usage of this statement is correct. If not, can someone explain to me about the try-catch statements usage.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UpdateStudent
    (@UpdateStudentDetails [UDTT_Stud] READONLY)
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.StudentDetails        --Deleted 'A' of UPDATE to give an  error
        SET FirstName = upStud.FirstName,
            LastName = upStud.Lastname,
            HomeAddress = upStud.HomeAddress,
            EmailAddress = upStud.EmailAddress
        FROM
            StudentDetails stud
        INNER JOIN
            @UpdateStudentDetails upStud ON stud.IndexNumber = upStud.IndexNumber
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS 'Error Message',
        ERROR_STATE() AS 'Error State',
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS 'Error Severity'
END CATCH
```

This is the output I get

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UpdateStudent, Line 5 [BatchStart Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near 'UPDATE'

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), try/catch doesn't catch syntax errors, only runtime errors.

Comment: Try a simple error e.g. `select convert(datetime, '12 juh 2019')`

Comment: Can you please the output windows result, what result you are getting?, Try catch syntax is correct, there might be some other issue. try-catch caught the runtime errors.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UpdateStudent, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near 'UPATE'.
@MukeshArora this is the output I get

Comment: This is a syntax error, will not be caught by the try-catch block, If any run-time error occurred that will be caught by the try-catch block. e.g. in your case let's assume that if the update statement failed due to referential integrity or updating the NULL value in not null columns that will caught by try-catch block. To verify this, comment your update statement and put this select 1 / 0 instead of update statement and run your procedure, you will see the try catch block works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say, you have a syntax error and not a runtime error that could be caught by the try...catch.

You have set an alias for the StudentDetails table, so you should use it instead of UPDATE StudentDetails.
I have also removed an unnecessary BEGIN END block inside 
the BEGIN TRY block, and added the outer BEGIN END for the entire stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UpdateStudent
    (@UpdateStudentDetails [UDTT_Stud] READONLY)
AS 
BEGIN -- The entire stored procedure should be inside a BEGIN END block
   BEGIN TRY
       UPDATE stud -- We use the alias
       SET FirstName = upStud.FirstName,
           LastName = upStud.Lastname,
           HomeAddress = upStud.HomeAddress,
           EmailAddress = upStud.EmailAddress
       FROM
           StudentDetails stud
       INNER JOIN
           @UpdateStudentDetails upStud ON stud.IndexNumber = upStud.IndexNumber
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
       SELECT
           ERROR_MESSAGE() AS 'Error Message',
           ERROR_STATE() AS 'Error State',
           ERROR_SEVERITY() AS 'Error Severity'
   END CATCH
END
```